# how to display data labels / stacklabels for a grouped highhcarts- Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm using React Js highcharts and I want to be able to display labels below my series value

Something like below but WITHOUT STACKING. I want them to be grouped like shown in fiddle below

[image]

I have got to working up to this:
https://jsfiddle.net/fp6ue5ox/

I want to display labels:

```
Active, confirmed, new
```

I tried adding the `stackLabels`, but it does still show up

```
chart: {
          type: 'column',
        },

        title: {
          text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
        },

        xAxis: {
          categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges'],
          offset: 30
        },
        yAxis: {
          allowDecimals: false,
          //offset:10,
          title: {
            text: 'Number of fruits'
          },
          stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
          }

        },

        plotOptions: {
          column: {
            stacking: ''
          },
        },

        series: [ {
          name: 'new',
          data: [33, 99, 88, 34, 73, 88],
    
           dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            overflow: 'none',
            crop: false,
            y: 20,
            formatter() {
              return this.series.userOptions.stack;
            }
          }
        },{
          name: 'reopened',
          data: [42, 54, 43, 62, 74, 84],
       
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            overflow: 'none',
            crop: false,
            y: 20,
            formatter() {
              return this.series.userOptions.stack;
            }
          }

        }, {
          name: 'active',
          data: [34, 40, 42, 36, 74, 83],
       
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            overflow: 'none',
            crop: false,
            y: 20,
            formatter() {
              return this.series.userOptions.stack;
            }
          }
        }]
      });
```

Any idea anyone?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please analyze this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2ouLy1vj/

In the formatter callback, you can set wanted format to display as a dataLabel.

```
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    overflow: 'none',
    crop: false,
    //y: 20,
    formatter() {
      return this.series.name;
    }
  }
```

Also, I copied the logic from your previous question: [how to determine the width of every column series present in the chart- highhcarts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64191416/how-to-determine-the-width-of-every-column-series-present-in-the-chart-highhcar)

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian: however I always find this confusing as to why the labels show at the top- like https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2ouLy1vj/ the label is ```active``` is showing at the top- not sure why

Comment: @user1234 - I am not sure what do you have in mind here? Could you explain more precisely?

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian- what I'm confused is---- in your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2ouLy1vj/ the ```active``` stack name is missing for the first 2 column series. I tried uncommenting the ```y:20``` and the ```active``` stack label started showing for all column series, except for the last one: like this- https://jsfiddle.net/L76dcg5u/ . This behaviour is what I'm not able to comprehend.

Comment: Setting `allowOverlap` for this dataLabel config should fix the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1s9xc5hn/